# When is the metric completion of a Riemannian manifold a manifold with boundary?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a connected smooth Riemannian manifold and denote by $(M,d)$ the induced metric space following by taking topological metric to be the infimum over length of curves in the standard way. Suppose that $(M,d)$ is not complete and let $(\hat{M},d)$ denote the metric completion.

What can be said about $(\hat{M},d)$ being a smooth manifold with smooth boundary?

Edit: Take e.g. any open rectangle in Euclidean space. Then the completion will have a boundary that is not smooth (at the corners).

Comment: isn't $\hat{M}=M \cup \partial M$ ?

Comment: Edited with the counter-example. The boundary should be smooth.

Comment: so all you have to do is to check if the homeomorphisms extend smoothly to $\partial M$ ?

Comment: Even worse, if you delete the center point from the letter "X", (as well as the  4 end points), you have a nice smooth manifold whose metric completion is not even a manifold with boundary.  If I had to, I'd guess the question is very hard to answer in general.  (Also, the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ for $x > 0$ is a perfectly good Riemannian manifold whose metric completion is the graph together with $\{0\}\times [-1,1]$, so fails to be a manifold terribly.)

Comment: @Jason DeVito : I don't understand how you think the metric completion of a manifold. for me the metric completion of a manifold is a manifold with boundary, and testing if the boundary is a smooth manifold is done for example with the pointing inwards vectors

Comment: @user1952009:  Based on Vertex's wording, I think we are to assume the metric completion of a Riemannian manifold is simply the usual metric space completion.  That is, form the Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, form the metric space $(M,d)$ with $d$ defined as the infimum among paths connecting points.  Then, take the usual metric space completion.  (One typical approach is using Cauchy sequences.)  Said another way, $\hat{M}$ is the completion of $M$ if there is a map $\phi:M\rightarrow \hat{M}$ with dense image with the property that $d_M(x,y) = d_{\hat{M}}(\phi(x), \phi(y)).$

Comment: @Jason DeVito, the question makes no reference to an ambient space, so I think I have an issue with your examples. For example, the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ for $x >0$ is geodesically complete (and by Hopf-Rinow, complete as a metric space), isn't it? The metric $d$ you described in your second comment is not the same metric it inherits as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @PhillipAndreae:  You're right (on both counts)!  So, I also have issues with my examples:  as you say, the path metric on the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ doesn't coincide with the restriction of the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  (Likewise on $X$ with center point deleted - the path metric gives the remaining components infinite distance.)  Sorry about that.  Nonetheless, I still suspect that the completion of a Riemannian manifold as a metric space can fail to be (homeomorphic to) a manifold (with or without boundary).

Comment: Why can't you take an open subset of Euclidean space whose closure is not a manifold, like the outside of the alexander Horned sphere?

Comment: Yes Jason deVito this is the metric completion I mean. It has a priori nothing to do with any boundary, in the sense of the usual definition with charts to $H^n$.

I think I have my answer from another source. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Vertex:  If you have the time, can you post the answer?  I'd be interested in knowing what it is.

Comment: @Jason DeVito: It is very specific. In the given context the boundary will identify with a smooth surface and thus the charts extend smoothly to the $x_n=0$-hyperplane. 

More specifically, there is a local diffeomorphism from $\tilde{M}$ to $dS^n/AdS^n$ such that the image of the metric completion will locally identify with a coisotropic vector hyperplane. From this it follows via pullback that the metric completion (via a pull-back Riemannian metric) will induce a smooth boundary.

But nothing very general...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example answering a slightly stronger question, from Jason DeVito's comment: Construct a connected Riemannian manifold whose metric completion is not homeomorphic to a topological manifold (with or without the boundary). The simplest example, I think, is:

Take 2-torus $T^2$ smoothly embedded in the unit sphere $S^3$. Now, consider the euclidean cone $C$ over $T^2$ in $R^4$. Then let $M= C- \{0\}$, equipped with the Riemannian metric $g$ induced from $R^4$. I claim that the metric completion of $(M,g)$ is homeomorphic to $C$. Indeed, if $(x_i)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(M, d_g)$ (where $d$ is the distance function associated with $(M,g)$), then, since $d(x,y)\le |x-y|$, it follows that $(x_i)$ is also a Cauchy sequence in $R^4$. Hence, its (euclidean) limit is in the closure of $M$ in $R^4$. Thus, we obtain a map $f: \overline{(M,d)}\to C$ sending the equivalence class of $(x_i)$ to its euclidean limit. It is easy to see that $f$ is continuous. We need to check that $f$ is bijective. Surjectivity of $f$ is clear by considering a sequence $x_i= \frac{1}{i} x$, where $x\in M$ is arbitrary. Let us check injectivity. Consider two Cauchy sequences $(x_i), (y_i)$ such that $\lim x_i= \lim y_i=0\in R^4$. We need to show that
$$
\lim_{i\to\infty} d(x_i, y_i)=0. 
$$ 
Let $s_i= |x_i|$, $t_i=|y_i|$. Define the point $z_i= \frac{t_i}{s_i} x_i$, hence, $|z_i|=|y_i|=t_i$. It is easy to check that $d(x_i, z_i)\to 0$. Therefore, $(z_i)$ is again a Cauchy sequence equivalent to $(x_i)$. Moreover, if $D$ is the diameter of $T^2$ with respect to its Riemannian metric, then $d(z_i, y_i)\le t_i D \to 0$. Hence, $(z_i)$ is also equivalent to $(y_i)$. Thus, $(x_i), (y_i)$ represent the same point of the metric completion of $(M,d)$. Injectivity of $f$ follows. A similar argument shows continuity of $f^{-1}$. Therefore, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Lastly, being a cone over a torus, $C$ is not a topological manifold (since removing the origin changes its fundamental group, which cannot happen for a topological manifold).

There are other examples one can construct, for instance, removing from the euclidean plane a suitable collection of disjoint closed round disks converging to a point. But proving that the metric completion is homeomorphic to the closure in the euclidean plane (which is also not a manifold since it is not locally simply connected) is a bit more painful.

Comment: Could you explain (or provide a reference) for the claim that removing the origin does not change the fundamental group of a topological manifold? This seems false: Removing a point from $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ clearly changes the fundamental group...

Comment: @AmorFati I was talking about manifolds of dimension 3 (or more). Of course, this fails for surfaces and curves.