# Completion of a riemannian manifold.

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Every metric space has a completion, and a Riemannian manifold has a structure of metric space.

Is it possible to extend a Riemannian manifold an that this extension keeps being a Riemannian manifold?

I think that the answer is no, but is there any easy counterexample?
At first, I thought about the cone without vertex as submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is not complete and if you complete it you lose the smooth structure, but possibly this is not a valid one, because I thought about the cone (with vertex) keeps being a manifold regarded as an abstract one.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but I don't think it's true.  Take the cone on $\mathbb{R}P^2$, which is not even a topological manifold because of the cone point.  If we remove the cone point, what's left can be given the structure of a smooth Riemannian manifold in such a way that the inclusion map is an isometric embedding in the metric sense.  Then the cone on $\mathbb{R}P^2$ *is* the completion, so is not a manifold.

Comment: If for you a manifold is a manifold without boundary, then the metric completion of an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the induced metric) is the closed interval which cannot be given the structure of a manifold without boundary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the metric completion of a Riemannian manifold a manifold with boundary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641188/when-is-the-metric-completion-of-a-riemannian-manifold-a-manifold-with-boundary)